# jQuery to limit the scope of a function to the targeted element only

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

The script below is a toggle function that's attached to several widgets in an admin panel.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery(document).on('click','.toggleExtras', function(e){
        jQuery('.extras').slideToggle();
        jQuery(this).text(function(el, old){
            return old == "Show Advanced Options" ? "Hide Advanced Options" : "Show Advanced Options";
        });
    });

});
```

It works great, but there's one problem I need to address. When I click the toggle for one widget, it triggers the function for all widgets that have the same class. I'm looking for suggestions to alter the function so that it only affects the widget that was clicked.

Since the widgets are all dynamic, I won't know in advance the widget IDs of the trigger element's parent, but I may be able to use the dom to pass that to the function.

For example, here's a typical widget. I've ended the code at the trigger element. Perhaps I could walk the dom back up to the main container element (id=widget-43_my_box_cats-4) in order to limit the slideToggle() to the children of that element only?

HTML:

```
<div id="widget-43_my_box_cats-4" class="widget">   
    <div class="widget-top">
        <div class="widget-title-action"></div>
        <div class="widget-title"><h4>Widget Title<span class="in-widget-title"></span></h4></div>
    </div>

    <div class="widget-inside" style="display: block;">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="widget-content">
                <p>
                    <label for="widget-my_box_cats-4-title">Title:</label>
                    <input class="widefat" id="widget-my_box_cats-4-title" name="widget-my_box_cats[4][title]" type="text" value="">
                </p>

                <fieldset><legend><span class="toggleExtras">Hide Advanced Options</span></legend>
```

Comment: Where's the `.extra` element in that markup ?

Comment: There are several elements that are children of the main container that have the extras class attached. Not shown here for brevity. They are below the toggle span.

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you how to target each `.extra` individually if we have no idea where they are in the markup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what properties & objects does "e" have from the section "function(e){" ? It should have e.target.id, so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery(document).on('click','.toggleExtras', function(e){
    jQuery('#'+e.target.id).slideToggle();
    jQuery(this).text(function(el, old){
        return old == "Show Advanced Options" ? "Hide Advanced Options" : "Show Advanced        Options";
     });
  });
});
```